# Cannot get a joined Kafka stream to run or output anything

Tags: java, scala, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

For the below code, both stream1 and stream2 run fine individually and I can see output, but the joined stream just doesn't log anything at all. I have a feeling it has something to do with the join window, but the data from both streams comes in at almost exactly the same time.

```
val stream = builder.stream(stringSerde, byteArraySerde, "topic")

val stream1 = stream
  .filter((key, value) => somefilter(key, value))
  .through(stringSerde, byteArraySerde, "topic1")

val stream2 = stream
  .filter((key, value) => someotherfilter(key, value))
  .through(stringSerde, byteArraySerde, "topic2")

val joinedStream = stream1
  .join(stream2, (value1: Array[Byte], value2: Array[Byte]) => {
    println("wont print anything")
    return somerandomdata
  },
  JoinWindows.of("othertopic").within(10000L),
  stringSerde, byteArraySerde, byteArraySerde)
```

Comment: A join-window is computed over the embedded record timestamps (ie, meta data that is contained in each record additionally to key and value). It would help if you print those timestamps for debugging. To access them, you need to use process() -- the given `context` object, contains the timestamp of the currently processed record (ie, the context is updated for each processed record).

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't the keys of both topic be te same in order to join them?

I think the Javadoc explains this :
https://kafka.apache.org/0102/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/JoinWindows.html

This might also be an interesting read :
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Kafka+Streams+Join+Semantics